# What does this symbol mean? (looks like a lower-right corner -- subject: manifolds theory)

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Below I have posted an excerpt of Lee's Book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" (page 371). I don't know what the symbol means that looks like a lower-right corner, and I cannot find it via the index, nor does any alternative source for the definition of the divergence operator have that symbol. If anybody could give a hint what it denotes I can maybe find the passage in the book where it is explained, that would be a HUGE help!!!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the interior product ([Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product), [MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InteriorProduct.html)). It's defined on page 334-336 of Lee's book:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oy. Does Lee use $\Lambda^k(V)$ to mean $(\Lambda^k(V))^{\ast}$?

Comment: I plead guilty.  In ISM, I used $\Lambda^k(V)$ to denote the space of alternating covariant $k$-tensors on $V$, which most people denote by $\Lambda^k(V^*)$. I also used various other non-standard notations for tensor spaces.  My notations were internally consistent and seemed to make sense at the time, but I soon decided they were mistaken, and I've regretted them ever since.  In the second edition (scheduled to be released around the end of July), I've switched to more standard notations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a vector field and $\omega$ a $k$-form. Then $\iota_X\omega = X ~\lrcorner~ \omega$ is the $(k-1)$-form defined by $$(\iota_X\omega)(V_1, \dots, V_{k-1}) = \omega(X,V_1, \dots, V_{k-1})$$ for any vector fields $V_1, \dots, V_{k-1}$. This is called the **interior product** of $X$ with $\omega$.